# Iterate through JSON array in webmethod using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, webmethod

I have this `JSON` `Array` of objects that represents 3 records

```
{"Data":[{"RecID":2383,"PrtStatus":true},{"RecID":3387,"PrtStatus":true},{"RecID":3388,"PrtStatus":true}]}
```

and I m trying to iterate through it. I built the following class for it

```
Public Class TblRegJoindata
    Dim p_RecID As Integer
    Dim p_status As Boolean

    Public Property RecID As Integer
        Get
            Return p_RecID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            p_RecID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PrtStatus As Boolean
        Get
            Return p_status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            p_status = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In my web method I can access the data but can't figure out a way to loop through them and store them

```html
<WebMethod> _
Public Function TblRegJoinUpd3(ByVal Data As List(Of TblRegJoindata))
    Dim x As Integer = Data(0).RecID
End Function
```

What I m Trying to do is something like this, I tried to implement it but using "length" property is not allowed

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Length - 1
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(i)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Boolean.Parse((i))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

**Update**

```html
<WebMethod> _
Public Function TblRegJoinUpd3(ByVal Data As List(Of TblRegJoindata))
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegjoinUpdRec", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            con.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Boolean.Parse(Data(i).PrtStatus)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return (Data.Count)
```

Return data.count is just for test purposes

Comment: You need to use Count property instead of Length. `Data.Count`.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya,,, I tried this for testing,,, Public Function TblRegJoinUpd3(ByVal Data As List(Of TblRegJoindata))
        For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
            Return Data(i).PrtStatus
        Next
    End Function,,,,, I get only the first value back instead of three,,,

Comment: Did you debug and check what is the count of Data?. Is for loop executed 3 times? Can you update you code in the question and expalin what is not working and how its not working? How it is expected to work?

Comment: oh, i will build up my logic and update my code above, i will send you once i finish,, thanks for the prompt response

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya,, I tested it and its working , the count is 3 and records are getting processed properly,, could you please post your comment as an answer so I mark it, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Chetan Ranpariya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884101/chetan-ranpariya)
The whole working solution is below

```html
Public Class TblRegJoindata
Dim p_RecID As Integer
Dim p_status As Boolean

Public Property RecID As Integer
    Get
        Return p_RecID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        p_RecID = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PrtStatus As Boolean
    Get
        Return p_status
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        p_status = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class

<WebMethod> _
Public Function TblRegJoinUpd3(ByVal Data As List(Of TblRegJoindata))
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TblRegjoinUpdRec", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            con.Open()
            For i As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Data(i).RecID)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrtStatus", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Boolean.Parse(Data(i).PrtStatus)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return (Data.Count)
```